# Why is $\varepsilon x^5 \sim -x$?

Tags: limits, polynomials, asymptotics, roots, perturbation-theory

I'm trying to understand what's going on in [this lecture on perturbation](https://youtu.be/LYNOGk3ZjFM?t=1h08m12s) (the link brings you to 1h 08m 12s).

The original problem is to find the real root of $$x^5+x=1.$$ We have inserted $\varepsilon$ as follows $$\varepsilon x^5+x=1$$ and are discussing which of the three terms ($\varepsilon x^5$ or $x$ or $1$) is negligible as $\varepsilon \to 0$ so we could throw it way.

So we consider all three cases and it turns out that:

1. Term $1$ is negligible and we learn something if we remove it,
2. Term $x$ is not negligible,
3. Term $\varepsilon x^5$ is negligible but we learn nothing if we remove it.

My question is about term $1$ being negligible. On the blackboard, we have $$\varepsilon x^5 \sim -x \quad \text{as} \quad \varepsilon \to 0$$ and claim that it's true. Why?

I thought it means $$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{\varepsilon x^5}{-x} = 1.$$ In fact, this is how it was defined it at the beginning of the lecture.

So what's going on here?

Comment: I don't know perturbation theory, but based on your description, I guess when 1 is negligible in the equation $\epsilon x^5+x=1$,  $x$ should be extremely large (compared to 1) and of course it should depend on the value of $\epsilon$. So if we see $x$ as a function of $\epsilon$, we should have $x\sim O(\epsilon^{-1/4})$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to look at this issue is to write the equation as
\begin{equation}
\epsilon x^5 = 1-x. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
When $\epsilon=1$, the situation is as shown in the picture below. Since $x^5$ is monotonically increasing (and $1-x$ is strictly monotonically decreasing), it's clear that $(1)$ has one real solution, where the two curves intersect.

Now, what happens if we take $\epsilon$ smaller and smaller? Then, the curve $\epsilon x^5$ will be 'flatter and flatter', until for $\epsilon = 0$, the curve coincides with the horizontal axis. From the figure, it is very clear what will happen to the point of intersection: as $\epsilon \to 0$, this point will converge to $x=1$, from the left.

[image: x^5 vs 1-x]

**However**, in the lecture, the relation $\epsilon x^5 \sim - x$ is **not** written down in the context of this only real root! The real root, which is close to $1$, is found on the *right side* of the blackboard. What the lecturer tries to accomplish by looking at the asymptotic regime where $\epsilon x^5 \sim - x$, is to find out if we can find an approximate expression for *the other four roots*, which are all fully complex. As he demonstrates, these can be approximated as
\begin{equation}
 x \sim \pm\frac{1\pm i}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\epsilon^{\frac{1}{4}}}.
\end{equation}
You can see that for these complex roots, we indeed have
\begin{equation}
 \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\epsilon x^5}{-x} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} -\epsilon x^4 = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  - \left(\frac{1\pm i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^4 = 1
\end{equation}

The idea behind the asymptotic statement '$\epsilon x^5 \sim - x$', as the lecturer explains in the video, is that we're looking for solutions to $(1)$ where $x$ is *very large*. In particular, we assume that $x$ is sufficiently large such that both $x \gg 1$ and $\epsilon x^5 \gg 1$. That means that these two terms dominate the equation, and we can neglect the term '$1$'. Another way to look at this is to divide $(1)$ by $x$, yielding
\begin{equation}
 \epsilon x^4 = \frac{1}{x} - 1. \tag{2}
\end{equation}
You can see that when $x$ is large, then the term $\frac{1}{x}$ goes to zero, so it is definitely much smaller than the term $-1$, and if you take $x$ large enough, then $\frac{1}{x}$ can also be made much smaller than $\epsilon x^4$. It is precisely this asymptotic regime that the lecturer is treating.

Comment: Thank you, that looks promising. But what is $x$ then? When he shows that $x \sim 1$ he must have had $$x(\varepsilon):= \text{the real root of } \varepsilon z^5+z=1$$ in mind, right? (I have the polynomial with $z$ as variable to prevent it from looking self-referential).

But when he shows $\varepsilon x^5 \sim -x$ he changes it to $$x(\varepsilon):= \text{one of the complex roots of } \varepsilon z^5+z=1,$$ right?

Comment: Not quite, Leo, you don't have a root in mind when you set the relations, you test all the relations to see which give a consistent balance. If $x\sim 1$, then you are looking for roots close to 1. If $\epsilon x^5\sim x$, then you are looking for roots close to $\epsilon^{-1/4}$. Note that he didn't do $\epsilon x^5\sim 1$, can you see why that wouldn't work? Frits, I hope you don't mind my comment, your answer was very nice again.

Comment: @David: No, of course not, I couldn't agree more! Thanks!

Comment: @David, Frits: thank you! But when we set the relations, $x$ is a function of $\varepsilon$, right? If so, it must be defined somehow. What is a rigorous way to think about it?

Comment: I like to think of it as $\epsilon$ parameterising a set of solutions $x$. Really, what you are doing is writing an asymptotic series for $x$, $x\sim x_0+\epsilon x_1+\epsilon^2 x_2+\ldots$. I'm sure if you keep watching the lectures you linked to you will learn more about that! Carl Bender also wrote a great book, (along with Orszag), called "Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers" which I highly recommend. If you are after a very rigorous treatment, maybe look at "Applied Asymptotic Analysis", by Miller. Another good book with some information about this is by Keuhn.

Comment: Just to add to that: for the more 'classical' asymptotic methods, I can also recommend P.A. Lagerstrom, *Matched Asymptotic Expansions: Ideas and Techniques*, Springer, 2010.